# SSRS - Rename Database

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs

Is there anyway to rename a SSRS database?  I am moving from SSRS 2005 to 2008 but want to fully test before I cut over to the new server.

The plan was to create a copy of the SSRS database and point the 2008 instance at the new DB.  That appears to work fine except event tough the configuration UI says I'm connecting to the new DB (and I confirmed with SQL Profiles that there are queries hitting the new DB).

However there are errors in the log file that show that its hitting the old DB and the old TempDB.

Is there anyway to tell SSRS to use the new DB name?  I searched in all the config files and I don't see the old DB name anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Per Microsoft, Renaming the report server database is not supported.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159093.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use the Reporting Services Configuration tool to direct SSRS to a different database.

Did you just copy the SSRS 2005 database and are now pointing 2008 at it?  I'm not sure what database schema differences there may be between an SSRS 2005 DB and one from SSRS 2008.

Comment: The Configuration tool is pointed at the new DB and I can see queries hitting the new DB, but the error logs show it trying to hit the old TempDB (the errors are permissions errors because the user doesn't have permissions on the old DBs).  SSRS 2008 will automatically upgrade your schema from 2005